# ProgressDialog - how to remove the numbers

Tags: android, progressdialog

I was following the progress dialog example in the ApiDemos.
all went great except for one thing - I want to remove the numbers that appear underneath the bar (those running numbers that run from 0 to .getMax().

couldn't find how to do it.

anyone?

Ori

Comment: Here is another example with code sample
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453152/2799526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looked through `ProgressDialog.java`, there's no official way.

The choices are:

- Subclass it, access `mProgressNumber` via reflection to `.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
- Write your own implementation.

Answer (score 67):

With api 11, we can do it by calling:

```
progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this code for Android < API Level 11. It uses reflection to set the visbility to GONE:

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        Method method = TextView.class.getMethod("setVisibility",
                Integer.TYPE);

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getSuperclass()
                .getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mProgressNumber")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(this);
                method.invoke(textView, View.GONE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Failed to invoke the progressDialog method 'setVisibility' and set 'mProgressNumber' to GONE.",
                e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I used your code to build my own that can also hide the percentage. thanks

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, **I use the answer of Martin** to build my class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    private int progressPercentVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
    private int progressNumberVisibility = View.VISIBLE;

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context, int progressPercentVisibility, int progressNumberVisibility) {
        super(context);

        this.progressPercentVisibility = progressPercentVisibility;
        this.progressNumberVisibility = progressNumberVisibility;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setFieldVisibility("mProgressPercent", progressPercentVisibility);
        setFieldVisibility("mProgressNumber", progressNumberVisibility);
    }

    private void setFieldVisibility(String fieldName, int visibility) {
        try {
            Method method = TextView.class.getMethod("setVisibility", Integer.TYPE);

            Field[] fields = this.getClass().getSuperclass()
                    .getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(this);
                    method.invoke(textView, visibility);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can also hide the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I took @MartinVonMartinsgrün's answer and modified it a little bit. This solution simply takes advantage of the API call in Honeycomb+, whereas it uses reflection to accomplish the same goal for Gingerbread and before.

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    dialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
} else {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext()) {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            try {
                Field field = ProgressDialog.class.getDeclaredField("mProgressNumber");

                field.setAccessible(true);
                TextView textView = (TextView)field.get(this);
                field.setAccessible(false);

                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Ignore the exception ... We'll just let the dialog show the bytes. It's not ideal but it works.
                Log.w("ProgressDialog", "Failed to hide the progress number via reflection.", e);
            }
        }
    };
}

// Further configure the dialog ...

dialog.show();
```