# How to remove progress bar number at the bottom part of the progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

How do I remove the encircled on the picture?

[image]

Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Comment: You would have to make your own progress bar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass `null` to `setProgressNumberFormat()` and `setProgressPercentFormat()` when you create your `ProgressDialog`. Note that this is only available on API Level 11 and higher.

Comment: Thanks for your response @CommonsWare, too bad I'm using API 8. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: @Emkey: Change to use API Level 11, or use reflection to call those methods. AFAIK, the progress number and percentage do not exist on prior versions of Android. Or, do not use `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: This is correct. The progress number AND percentage will also be displayed in prior API levels. Iam also searching for a workaround

Comment: @CommonsWare How can i show progress with KB/MB downloaded. I would like to show the progress same as when we download the app from the Play store.

Comment: @CommonsWare Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101562/how-to-show-kb-mb-as-progress-in-android-using-progressdialog# if you can guide me than it would be great. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I needed a similar functionality -> to hide the percenatge and min/max when the progressDialog is in indeterminate state.

```
private void setIndeterminate(boolean isIndeterminate) {
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(isIndeterminate);
    if (isIndeterminate) {
        progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
        progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
    } else {
        progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d/%2d");
        NumberFormat percentInstance = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        percentInstance.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(percentInstance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the above number status from progress dialogue, then you should remove this code.

```
progress1.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

Here i will show you that how to create progress bar which will not show any status

```
progress1.setMessage("Fetching Files...! ");
progress1.setIndeterminate(true);             
 progress1.show();
```