# remove percentage shown below the progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, percentage

I am getting the percentage below the horizontal progress dialog.
I want to remove that.

I got the method  setProgressPercentFormat(null), but that work in api level 11 or higher.
I need to do in api level 8.

So, how can I do that?
Please help me.

I also got the suggestion to customize my progressDialog, but don't know how to do that. Please direct me.

Comment: Use ProgressBar instead of horizontal progress dialog

Comment: I think you can use **seekbar** instead of **Horizontal progress dialog** to remove percentage.

Comment: You have a custom progress bar example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454450/669180

Comment: You can implement your own ProgressDialog or just copy implementation from Android sources

Comment: Alright Steelight, but that seems to be the progress bar, but what in the case of ProgressDialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing null to setProgressNumberFormat() and setProgressPercentFormat() may help you out.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794001/how-to-remove-progress-bar-number-at-the-bottom-part-of-the-progress-bar) for more details.